# html output formatting php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to format some html output from my db using php and here's my problem:

How it should be formated:

```
...
<li>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
       <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-1</div>
       <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-2</div>
       <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-3</div>
       <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
      <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-5</div>
      <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-6</div>
      <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-7</div>
      <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
      <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-9</div>
      <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-10</div>
      <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-11</div>
      <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-12</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-13</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-14</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-15</div>
    <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-16</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-17</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-18</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-19</div>
    <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-21</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-22</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-23</div>
    <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-24</div>
  </div>
</li>
... etc.
```

Data is held inside an array gathered from mysql db, so far I got to this:

```
$num_thumbs = 4; //Number od elemets in a row
$result = myQueryFunction("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY Id ASC"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if (!empty($num_rows)) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $thumbs_array[] = "<a href=\"" . $row[0] . "\"><img src=\"" . $row[1] . "\"";
  }
  $thumb_p = "<div>\n";
  mysql_free_result($result);
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($thumbs_array as &$thumb_link) {
    if ($i == $num_thumbs) {
        $i = 1;
        $thumb_p .= "<div class=\"some-class-2\">" . $thumb_link . "</div>";
        $thumb_p .= "</div>\n<div class=\"row-wrapper\">\n";
    } else {
            $thumb_p .= "\t\n<div class=\"some-class-1\">" . $thumb_link . "</div>";
        $i++;
    }

  }
  $thumb_p .= "\n</div>\n";
}

print($thumb_p);
```

this covers only this part of code formatting:

```
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-13</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-14</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-15</div>
    <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-16</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-17</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-18</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-19</div>
    <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-21</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-22</div>
    <div class="some-class-1">ARRAY-ELEMENT-23</div>
    <div class="some-class-2">ARRAY-ELEMENT-24</div>
  </div>
```

I've been thinking of using some variable $newList = null; that will be updated at each row, so I can check if it has changed the next one.
any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Um, maybe because I don't see an `<li>` anywhere in your PHP??

Comment: While tables should not be used for layout, that data looks an awful lot like tabular data - maybe use a table? Not that this helps your problem, but I just though I'd throw that in there...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart nope I can't figure out where to put it.

Just need help how to include "<li>" inside code snippet, because i don't know exact number of array elements.

Comment: @DaveRandom hmm, nope, no table's :)

Comment: copy data to an array, an chunk that array in the correct sizes using array_chunk()

Comment: I can't see the <li> tag in your code either... That's an awful lot of code that makes it more difficult to find the answer for you: next time just the necessary snippets.

Comment: @Danny As I said earlier there is no `<li>` tag in the code, just cant figure out how to include it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to put an li every three div. In this case, you can do this :

```
$thumb_p = "<li>\n<div class=\"row-wrapper\">\n";
mysql_free_result($result);
$i = 1;
$j = 0;
foreach ($thumbs_array as &$thumb_link) {
  if ($i == $num_thumbs) {
      $i = 1;
      $thumb_p .= "<div class=\"some-class-2\">" . $thumb_link . "</div>";
      $thumb_p .= "</div>\n";
      if($j == 3)
      {
          $thumb_p .= "</li>\n<li>";
          $j = 0;
      }
      $thumb_p .= "<div class=\"row-wrapper\">\n";
      $j++;
  } else {
      $thumb_p .= "\t\n<div class=\"some-class-1\">" . $thumb_link . "</div>";
      $i++;
  }
}
$thumb_p .= "\n</div>\n</li>\n";
```

I can't actually try it but I think it's okay. A li is added every three row-wrapper you print.

Comment: Yes that would be it, although this code put's an '<li>' every 4 div! :)